# How does trust work in PGP?

Tags: pgp

I am trying to understand in detail how does one "express" trust in someone else's public key in PGP.

As far as I know, in PGP you associate uids (for simplicity, say that these are emails) to public keys, and this trust assignment process says (or should say) something like "I trust that key 0x1234 belongs to user alice@email.com".

In GPG clients, this process seems to be performed in practice via the `tsign` (trust signing action) command stated in the [GPG manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/OpenPGP-Key-Management.html). However, this manual does not specify *what* is being signed, and refers to [this section of RFC-4880](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-5.2.3.13). Therein, nothing is said either about *what* is being signed (it simply talks about trust levels).

Now, *what* is being signed is crucial.

Take the example above, in which Carol says "I trust that key 0x1234 belongs to user alice@email.com". But then, assume that the owner of alice@email.com starts using key 0x1234 from bob@email.com. Carol's trust should not apply there, as she does not know who is the owner of bob@email.com. But, if the `tsign` command above does not bind 0x1234 with alice@email.com (e.g., if it only signs 0x1234), Carol's trust may be misinterpreted.

Can someone refer to some spec (or code) that clearly defines what is being signed? I don't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: I think you get some fundamentals wrong. A key belongs to a user. If you trust a key you thus trust that the specific user who owns the key is also the one who uses it. Somebody else could only use the same key if they have access to the matching private key - which they should never have (it is called "private" for a reason). So there is nothing like *"... assume that the owner of alice@email.com starts using key 0x1234 from bob@email.com."* - they simply can't.

Comment: Ok, that kind of makes sense. Except that then, what does not make sense is the GPG client showing uids alongside key fingerprints -- that kind of says "this key belongs to this uid".

Re: "... assume that the owner of alice@email.com starts using key 0x1234 from bob@email.com." - they simply can't." this can happen, if whoever owns alice@email.com is also the owner of bob@email.com -- or, of course, if the private key gets compromised (although that's another issue).

Anyway, if you can point to a concrete spec or source code that specifies what is being signed, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: RFC 4880 5.2 is about the subpackets which binds information __to public keys__. Specifically section 5.2.3.13 is about "Trust Signature" which describes how much a key is trusted.

Comment: Thanks! Was just reading around that section too.

Section 5.2.1 defines the types of signatures. Types 0x10-0x13 bind uid and public key with different degrees of "certainty". Then, Section 5.2.4 specifies how to compute a signature. Concretely, for types 0x10-0x13, it says "A certification signature (type 0x10 through 0x13) hashes the User ID being bound to the key into the hash context after the above data."

So that fully addresses the doubt. Both uid and pk are bound in one single signature.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: nit: nowadays we call asymmetric keys public and private, but when Phil Z started they were called public and secret, and lots of things still reflect this: packets 5 and 7 are Secret [sub]key, GPG commands are `--list-secret-keys/-K --export-secret-keys` etc, although an armored secret-key file is labelled `BEGIN/END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK`. Worse, [Bouncycastle uses both](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.bouncycastle/bcpg-jdk18on/latest/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/package-summary.html)